# How to return a 2D array using Reflection?

Tags: java, arrays

***Purpose of Code***

To find out what picture is on the screen by comparing it with an already existing set of pixels, which are in the form of methods that return 2D arrays, in the `DataStoragePics` Class.

***How I tried to Solve it***

1. Using reflection I stored all the methods from `DataStoragePics` class in the `methodStorage[]`.
2. Then I invoke a method from `methodStorage[]` which will then store in a `tempMatrix[][]`.
3. Using a loop and another method (not shown here) I will later use to find out what type of Picture the captured set of pixels are.

***What I need help with***

When I try to solve the problem by using the steps mentioned above I get an error on the third line from the bottom in the main class repeated twice:

> Multiple markers at this line - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to int.

I think the problem is `methodStorage[x].invoke(DataStoragePicsObj)` is a single array but it return a 2D array and the program doesn't recognize that so it needs either the `tempMatrix` to be a simple array or the `methodStorage[]` to be a 2D array.  I need help solving that error.

This is the `Main` Class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

  int [][] tempMatrix = new int[16][450];

//Creates a DataStoragePics Object.
  DataStoragePics DataStoragePicsObj = new DataStoragePics();
//Stores all DataStoragePics methods in methods[].
  Method[] methodStorage = DataStoragePicsObj.getClass().getMethods();

//Loops through methodStorage[].
  for(int x = 0; x < method.length; x++)
  {
      //Stores a 2D array from DataStoragePics class in tempMatrix.
      //All methods in DataStoragePics return a 2D array with [16][10] dimensions.

      /*This is the error line*/ 
      tempMatrix[16][10] = methodStorage[x].invoke(DataStoragePicsObj);
      /*above is the error line*/
  }
```

This is Part of the `DataStoragePics` class:

```
public class DataStoragePics
{

  public int[][] picXYZ()
    {
      int[][] rgbValues = 
      {
        {1,2,3,4},
        {9,8,7,6}
      };

      return rgbValues;
    }
}
```

I am bit of a beginner when it come to java/coding so please don't use complicated terms.

**Syllabus's answer helped but I am still getting this error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to [[I" The thing is casting and it stores and returns stuff on the screen. Sometimes it shows the error at the end sometimes in the middle.  Don't know why.**

Comment: What is `tempMatrix`'s type? You haven't shown us how you create that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through **all** the methods in your class. And casting the return value of each of these methods to `int[][]`.

```
Method[] methodStorage = DataStoragePicsObj.getClass().getMethods();

//Loops through methodStorage[].
  for(int x = 0; x < method.length; x++)
```

This is of course going to fail, because your `DataStoragePicsObj` class implicitly extends `java.lang.Object` which has methods like `hashCode`, `toString` and `getClass` that do not return `int[][]`.

If you invoke a method through reflection, you should be prepared to pass it the right arguments and the process it's return value; if you cannot, you shouldn't invoke the method through reflection.

What you could do - if my understanding of what you want to do is correct - is to check the return type and also the arguments to make sure that you are prepared to handle the reflective invocation:

```
    Method m = methodStorage[x];
    if (m.getReturnType() != int[][].class || m.getParameterTypes().length != 0) {
        // Skip this method because it requires arguments or doesn't return int[][]
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: All the methods from the DataStoragePics class return int[][] there are no methods with any other return type no void methods, no int methods, no double, no char, no string, no float, no int[], none of these types just    int[][].

Comment: @user3144079 Please read my answer again. `DataStoragePicsObj` inherits methods from `java.lang.Object` (like any Java class does, you can't suppress this) Why don't you try my solution and check if it works?

Comment: @user3144079 If you add a statement `System.out.println(methodStorage[x].getName())` you'll find that the method that is causing your exception is called `getClass`.

Comment: I tried the solution and I did the getName() thing and I understand it now and the problem is fixed.  Thank you for taking the time after answering.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with no "cast", the compiler just considers that `invoke` return an `Object`.

`tempMatrix[16][10]` represents the element (16, 10) in your `tempMatrix` array, so its type is an `int`.

So assigning an Object to an int raises a compiler error: types before an after the "=" must be the "same".

First, you must cast the Object returned by invoke to a `int[][]`.
Then you must assign to a int[][] object (the full tempMatrix?)

```
tempMatrix = (int[][]) methodStorage[x].invoke(DataStoragePicsObj);
```